# How to Call a Function From a JSON Array

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I’m trying to figure out how I can call a function in my project without using so many if Statements.  The concept using the if statement works great.  But every time I create a new function call, I have to write a new if statement.  What I am hoping to do is add the new function call in my JSON Array and invoke my function(s) that way.  I’m currently loading my data from a JSON Array by the way of D3, I’m hoping to add the function call that way.  Below is a copy of my working concept with the if statements, which works great.

```
 var funcData;

 d3.csv("data/pointData5.csv", function(error, data) {
funcData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
     console.log(funcData);
     var select = d3.select("#selectL")
  .append("div")
  .append("select")
 select
 .on("change", function() {
var v = d3.select(this).property("value");
 if (v == 2) {
        updateDataA(); 
  }
 if (v == 3) {
        updateDataB(); 
  }
 if (v == 4) {
        updateDataC();
  }
 if (v == 5) {
        updateDataD(); 
      }
})
select.selectAll("option")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("option")
   .attr('class',  function(d,i) { return 'option' + i;})
   .attr("value", function (d) { return d.value; })
   .text(function (d) { return d.label; })
  });
```

Below is the concept I’m trying to get working but I can’t seem to get working.  The function name loading but it won’t call the function like the script does above.

```
var funcData;

d3.csv("data/pointData5.csv", function(error, data) {
funcData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(funcData);
var select = d3.select("#selectL")
     .append("div")
     .append("select")
    select
        .on("change", function() {
        var v = d3.select(this).property("value");
        for (var i = 1; i <  funcData.length; i++)
    if (v == i && funcData[i].dataF) {
        console.log(funcData[i].dataF);
        funcData[i].dataF;
  }
})
select.selectAll("option")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("option")
    .attr('class',  function(d,i) { return 'option' + i;})
    .attr("value", function (d) { return d.value; })
    .text(function (d) { return d.label; })
});
```

Below is a screen capture of my JSON Array.
[image: Screen Capture of JSON Object from Console]

I really appreciate if anyone can offer a solution or if this concept is even possible.  Thank you in advance.

Added Edition of what the function is invoking:

```
 updateDataA();

 function updateDataA() {
 updateData("gTank.png");
}
function updateDataB() {
updateData("bTank.png");
}
function updateDataC() {
updateData("diamond.svg");
}

////////////Add Markers to Map//////////////////
function updateData(url) {
removeMarkers()
omnivore.csv('data/pointData5.csv') 
    .on('ready', function(layer) {
    this.eachLayer(function(marker) {
         if (marker.toGeoJSON().properties.graphic != url) 
             marker.remove();
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Add a flyTo button
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          var button = document.createElement("button");
          button.className += " myBtns";
                if(marker.toGeoJSON().properties.graphic == url) {
                    button.innerHTML  = 
            marker.toGeoJSON().properties.cityName;
                    $('.zoomPoint').append(button);
        }
       // button.innerHTML = marker.toGeoJSON().properties.cityName;
        button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
         // map.flyTo(layer.getLatLng(), 5); // This works obviously,
     but just to demonstrate use of xy conversion:
            map.flyTo(xy(marker.toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates), 9, {
                animate: true,
                duration: 2.5
        });

          map.once("moveend", function () {
            marker.openPopup();
          });
        });

     ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 


    //Load Icons from CSV file  
        var customIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'graphic/' + 
   marker.toGeoJSON().properties.graphic,//add graphic from CSV file
            iconSize: [20, 10 ], //size of the icon in pixels
            iconAnchor: [9, 9], //point of the icon which will
   correspond to marker's location (the center)
            popupAnchor: [0, 0] //point from which the popup should 
   open relative to the iconAnchor
  });
 //Add ID to each image - can now style each icon with CSS
 $('#map').find('img').each(function (i) {
$(this).attr('id', 'img_');
 });    

  $(".content ").find(".myBtns:first-child").prop("disabled", true);
         //change the icons for each point on the map
        marker.setIcon(customIcon);
         //create popup with text and image - click image in popup,
   large image displays in fancybox
        var popupText =
             marker.bindPopup('<strong>' +
  marker.toGeoJSON().properties.cityName + '</strong>' + ', ' + '</br>'
+ marker.toGeoJSON().properties.discrip +  "<br /><a class='fancybox- 
thumb' ' style='width:150px;' rel='fancybox-button'  rel='fancybox- 
 thumb' data-fancybox-group='"+ marker.toGeoJSON().properties.popup +"'
title='" + marker.toGeoJSON().properties.discrip + " '   
href='graphic/"+ 
marker.toGeoJSON().properties.popup + "' ><img src='graphic/" + 
marker.toGeoJSON().properties.popup + "' alt='Image' '  s
 style='width:150px;'
   ></a>" + "<br/><a href='http://www.google.com' 
     target='_blank'>Cedellion Report</a>");
   });
     }).addTo(map);
    }
```

Comment: Could you use eval and the value dataF which appears to be the name of the function you are calling?

Comment: I read up on that method and I tried a few provided example, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: After a little more research I found my solution, the eval().  This was M. Page and Richik suggestion....thank you.  To do what I was seeking to accomplish, I added my function in my loop like this, eval('(' + funcData[i].dataF + ')'); and everything worked as I hoped.  Thank you all for putting me on the correct path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>You could use `eval()`, but that is highly discouraged. There are other options to do this, but most likely you could do some rearchitecture here. What do your `updateDataA()`, `updateDataB()`, and `updateDataC()` functions do? How different are they from each other? Most likely you could refactor to have a single `updateData` function that takes a parameter based on the current array element and updates data accordingly. I'm going to need some more details before I can fully answer your question.</del>

The best way to go about this is to store the URL in the JSON array (e.g. `"url": "gTank.png"`) and then call the `updateData()` function passing in the `url` property.

```
let url = d3.select(this).property("url");
updateData(url);
```

This is probably the best practice way to do it, as eval is a security risk and highly discouraged.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  I edited my original post to include script of the function I'm invoking.  I'm using a CSV file and D3 to populate an option select list.  I 'm currently converting the CSV to JSON via D3 and placing the data in a global variable to invoke the function, to replace my if statement concept.

Comment: After a little more research I found my solution, the eval().  This was M. Page and Richik suggestion....thank you.  To do what I was seeking to accomplish, I added my function in my loop like this, eval('(' + funcData[i].dataF + ')'); and everything worked as I hoped.  Thank you all for putting me on the correct path.

Comment: @TonyT Don't use eval. It's a hacky workaround and a security risk. I mentioned that it was highly discouraged earlier. I've updated my answer with a proper way to do it after examining your `updateData` methods.

Comment: I placed your concept in and it worked great.  I up voted the answer because not only it worked because it corrected the security risk!!!! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can store functions in array. But it is necessary to add parentheses for the call.

**Try**

```
if (v == i && funcData[i].dataF) {
    console.log(funcData[i].dataF);
    funcData[i].dataF(); // see the parentheses
}
```

You can also use this code to check that it is a function before the call

```
if(typeof funcData[i].dataF === 'function') {
}
```

**Examples**

```
let funcs = [
    (a, b) => { return a+b; },
    (a, b) => { return a-b; },
    () => { return true; }
];

funcs[0](2, 4); // return 6
funcs[1](2, 4); // return -2
funcs[2](); // return true
```

or

```
let funcs = {
    addition: (a, b) => { return a+b; },
    soustraction: (a, b) => { return a-b; }
};

funcs.addition(2, 4); // return 6
funcs['addition'](2, 4); // return 6
funcs.soustraction(2, 4); // return -2
funcs['soustraction'](2, 4); // return -2
```

Comment: I modified my script to add the parentheses for the call, nothing happened. But I have a question, my JSON reads updateDataA();.  Do I remove the parentheses from the JSON name?  The JSON will now read like this updateDataA.  I tried that way and it didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

After a little more research I found my solution, the eval().  This was M. Page and Richik suggestion....thank you.  To do what I was seeking to accomplish, I added my function in my loop like this, eval('(' + funcData[i].dataF + ')'); and everything worked as I hoped.  Thank you all for putting me on the correct path.